# dropdown menu is not working in magento admin panel.I got error of js as follows

Tags: magento2

dropdown menu is not working in magento admin panel.When I check in console i got this error

http://www.ethnicfashionboutique.com/skin/m/1399474730/js/prototype/prototy…minhtml/product.js,/js/calendar/calendar.js,/js/calendar/calendar-setup.js Failed to load resource:

Please give me any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

run command

```
bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

this issue will happen when you install magento2 freshly

Comment: i did not install,it happend automatically and i have tried this but i am getting error.please give me any other solution